# Model.create does not save to DB

Tags: python, django

I am trying to save an instance of a model to the database as described in this article:

Create method from `Promo` class:

```
@classmethod
def create(cls, discount_money):
    promo = cls(discount_money=discount_money)

    return promo
```

---

```
@staticmethod
def create_promo():
    promo = Promo.create(config.SUBSCRIPTION_DISCOUNT)
    print promo # => DHLI67LZ80T7AU1O
    print promo.discount_money # => 20000

self.create_promo()
```

But nothing appears in my DB. What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you defining a new `create` method on the model, when you can use [`create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.create) on the manager for the same effect? I.e. `obj = Promo.objects.create(discount_money=discount_money)` will save the Promo object to the database and return it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither method ever calls `save`, so nothing will be reflected in the database.

You need to make sure you call `save` in at least one of those methods. Probably makes more sense in the `create` method.

```
@classmethod
def create(cls, discount_money):
    promo = cls(discount_money=discount_money)
    promo.save()

    return promo
```

Comment: @ViktorDanilov - That is an unrelated error to your question, if either of these answers solved *this* problem, you should consider accepting one. You could always ask a new question complete with what you have tried researched if you get stuck with your other one

Answer (score 1):

As it is mentioned in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/):

> Note that instantiating a model in no way touches your database; for
>   that, you need to save().

Therefore you need to add `promo.save()` to your code:

```
@classmethod def create(cls, discount_money):
    promo = cls(discount_money=discount_money)
    promo.save()
    return promo
```